# Show/Hide Labels and Set Colors depending on Logged in Viewer

Tags: tableau-api

Using latest version - & online:

I have a group of Viewers that contribute their data to a common Chart (multi-line) - we union all the data.

I would like to have all the lines in grey with no label - except for the data line belonging to the logged in Viewer?  They would have their line colored red and also show a label (details etc).

I understand how to configure 'row filters' using the user-id.

But this is slightly different where all the rows are present - just the showing/hiding of labels & colouring of lines according to who's viewing the chart.

Thanks in advance!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Tableau forum:

> In principle, you'd want a couple of calculated fields to set color
>   and label text.  You'd have to a mechanism to tie the logged in user's
>   Tableau ID to a specific subset of the data, though, so that you can
>   determine what to do if the username matches the data.  Can you build
>   a relationship somehow between the data behind each line and a set of
>   users?